# How to decrease the array float data

Tags: java, floating-point

```
float datay [] = {32.534,46.436,7.777,63.463,3.453,3.453}
```

I want to change its data like this at once.. 
datay [] = {32.0,46.0,7.0,63.0,3.0,3.0}, how to do it?? please help me..

Comment: as side note: those here: 32.534,46.436,7.777,63.463,3.453,3.453 are doubles....

Comment: Do you mean, convert them to ints?

Comment: What have you tried? Without thinking of the code, what are logical steps that you think need to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Math.floor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor(double)) to reduce each float to the value of the nearest integer below it. `floor` uses `double`, so you would have to cast the result back to `float` when you put it back into your `float` array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < datay.length; ++i) {
    datay[i] = (float) Math.floor(datay[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood this right, but iterating on the array and using `Math.floor(datay[i])` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using `doubles` here, like

```
double datay [] = {32.534,46.436,7.777,63.463,3.453,3.453}
```

Also, to get the `Integer` part use [`Math#floor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor-double-)

```
for(int i=0;i<datay.length;i++){
    datay[i] = Math.floor(datay[i]);
}
```